# Using python on windows 7 and 10

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.5

Recently been having trouble using python on my laptop. I used to have windows 8.1 in my laptop, but saw most of my classmates use python with windows 10. So I updated to windows 10. Still having problems. I ended up using my desktop which has windows 7 and it worked perfectly. The problems have been when I would try and plot graphs or when id use arange. My question is, does windows really play a factor on python? they both have python version 3.5.1 python build 4 and 144 installed packages.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import exp, expm1
from __future__ import division
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Can you provide the specifics of what sort of error would be generated when using numpy's `arange`? This shouldn't be an issue, but it's worth investigating with more detailed advice...

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-59c835fbe009> in <module>()
      3 h= 10.71 #Height from balcony to ground in meters.
      4 n= int(T/dt)
----> 5 t=arange(0,T,dt)
      6 g=-9.8 #Meters per second squared
      7 m=.002714 #Mass of ping pong ball in kilograms

NameError: name 'arange' is not defined

Comment: So the issue is that `arange` isn't defined. Can you try something simpler in your Python file, like just `from numpy import arange` instead othe stuff above?

Comment: when I made the change the kernel died

Comment: Lol. Switch to Linux, we have no such ptoblems. :) Good luck, though.

Comment: never used Linux, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with windows. Either way you can uninstall python and reinstall it,may resolve your problem. But make sure you have installed numpy as well.You can get package for that http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy . Python installation has nothing to do with your windows version.

Comment: i have uninstalled and reinstalled python multiple times and no luck. Install numpy how? I always just put it on the first cell. Thank you.

Comment: you can get numpy package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/